# WCF performance

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

We have a table in our database which has around 2,500,000 rows (around 3GB). Is it technically possible to view the data in this table in a silverlight application which queries this data using WCF? Potentially, I see issues with the maximum buffer size and timeout errors. We may need the entire data to be used for visualization purposes.

Please guide me if there is a practical solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you need to show 3GB of data in single point of time? Do you understand that Silverlight is running on the client? Simply try to copy 3GB file over network and then imagine that WCF is slower - you will see that it will not work this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving 3GB to a client is not going to work.

> for visualization purposes.

Better prepare the visualization server-side. That will be slow enough.

Comment: Yes, it will be slow. We realize that. Users wanted Google finance like charts which show historical data for last 35 years.. Google Finance charts are interactive too and that is what we are trying to replicate using silverlight..

Comment: Still, you need to separate it. The SL-client is UI and holds/loads  data at the user-scale.

Comment: @JohnC: But Google Finance charts are processed on the server. Install Firefox and Firebug and use Net tab to check amount of transfered data. I just browsed Broadcom Corporation and it works with 211KB of tranfered data. It dynamically requery (AJAX) the server if you zoom or scroll the graph - it works only with amout of data which are really displayed - btw. it is essential in any visualization.

Comment: In a case like this as the others mentioned, your WCF call should be to tell the server what you want to visualize. The server does the work and sends a result back. Most clients won't be able to handle a data set that large to do their own visualization, even if they could download it in a reasonable timespan (which they can't).

Answer (score 4):

Generally in this sort of situation if you need to view individual records then you would use a paging strategy.  So your call to WCF would be for a page worth of records and you would display those records and the user would click on a next / previous button or some such.

As for the visualisation you should look to perform some transformation / reduction on the server as 2.5 million records is akin to displaying one data point per pixel on your screen.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Transfering 3GB of data from Disk to Disk can take quite a few minutes let alone on crossing across the network. I think you have got bigger fishes to fry - WCF limitation is irrelevant here.

So let's assume after a few minutes/hours you got the data across teh wire, where do you store it? You Silverlight app if running inside the browser can not grow to 3GB (even on a 64bit machine) and even it could, it does not make any sense. Especialy that amount of data when transformed into objects will take a lot more space.

Here is what I would do:

- Get the server to provide snapshots/views of the data that is useful, e.g. providing summary, OLAP cubes, ...
- For each record, provide minimum data required.
- If you need detail on each record, do that in a separate call

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe and suggest that you're not going to show 2,5 milion rows in the same listing.

If you develop a good paging of data and the way you query the data is optimal, I don't find the problem with WCF.

I'm agree with querying data with a WCF interface is less efficient than a standalone, direct access to infraestructure solution, but if you need to host some business and data and N clients to access that in a SOA solution, or it's a client-server solution, you'll need to be sure that your queries are efficient.

Suggestions:

- Use an OR/M. NHibernate will be your best choice, since it has a lot of ways of tweaking performance and paging is made easy because of it's LINQ support through QueryOver API in NHibernate 3.0. This product has a very interesting caching scheme and it'll let your application efficiently visualize your 2,5 milion-rows database.
- Do caching. NHibernate may help you in this area, but think about that and, depending on the client technology (Web, Windows...), you'll find good options for caching presentation views (ASP.NET output caching, for example).
- Think about how you're going to serialize objects in WCF: SOAP or JSON? Maybe you would be interested in JSON because serialized objects are tiny enough in order to save network trafic.

If you have questions, just comment out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after many users talk about what you do there technically - what is the sense someone without thinking thought you have there?

- 2.5 million rows make no sensein a grid. Zero. Showing 80 rows per page (wide sdcreen, tilted 90 degree) that would be 31250 pages worth of data. You can not even scripp to a specific page. Ignoring load times -even IF (!) you load that etc., it just makes no sense to have this amount ina  grid. Filter it down, then load what you need page wise. But the key here is to force the user to filter BEFORE even thinking about a grid. And once you ahve them, lets not get into takling abuot the performance of the grid.
- To show you how bad this is. For get the grid. If you assign ONE PIXEL or every data item, you take 1.33 screens of 1024*768 pixels to show the data. THis is one pixel per item.

So, at the end of the day, even IF (which is impossible) to manage to get this working, you end up with a non sensical / non usable applciation.